# How to cast int to Uint8 in Dart?

Tags: dart, casting, endianness

Currently, I am trying to read a file byte by byte and add some specific values to a list of 8-bit bytes (which might be of type `List<Uint8>`). To read the file one byte at a time, I am using `RandomAccessFile.readByte()`, but it returns an `int` value which is not accepted by `List<Uint8>.add()` function.

Due to the function name and return type, it looks like `RandomAccessFile.readByte()` provides a single byte in 64 bits. So what is the proper way to get only the least significant byte of the 64 bit result and add it to `_someUint8List` considering different types of endianness?

Lastly, [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736379/casting-an-int-to-uint8-in-dart) mentions Uint8 being a marker in Dart, but I am not sure what is meant by that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what type `Uint8` is.

If it's the type from `dart:ffi`, then it's a native type, which means you *cannot* have a Dart value with that type. If you read a `Pointer<Uint8>`, it returns the value as an `int`, and you write an `int` to it as well, which gets truncated on write.

Which means that you most likely *don't* have a `List<Uint8>`. You cannot, since there are no values of type `Uint8` in the Dart heap. It's a native type that has to be converted to a Dart value, an `int`, when you access it from native memory.

Use an `Uint8List` if the bytes are stored in the Dart heap, or a [`Uint8Array`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-ffi/Uint8Array.html) if they're stored in the native heap.

Comment: So when I use Uint8 do I utilize the native heap which is not reachable by Dart heap? Then theoratically, I could solve this issue by using file read functions from native libraries, right ?

Comment: When you write `Uin8` in Dart code, you refer to a type which has no instances in the Dart heap. It's a marker type for `dart:ffi` to know the native argument or return value layout, so that the Dart arguments can be marshalled into the correct layout, and the return values converted back, when calling a native function.
If you use native code to read a file, e.g., by calling native `fopen`, `malloc`,`fread` and `fclose` functions, then you can probably use a `Pointer<Uint8>` to refer to the data that you allocated in the native heap. Maybe even `Array<Uint8>`. (I'm not a `dart:ffi` expert.)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't want to use a `List<Uint8>`, but a `Uint8List`.

```dart
final list = Uint8List(<amount of bytes in the file>);

...

final byte = randomAccessFile.readByte();
list.add(byte);
```

you can also read the whole file into a `List<int>` buffer and then create a `Uint8List` from that with `RandomAccessFile.readInto`.

But what I suspect that you want to do is not using `RandomAccessFile` at all, but just read in your file directly to a `Uint8List`:

```dart
final file = File(path);
Uint8List uint8list = await file.readAsBytes();
```

Or if you really want to go from a `List<int>` to a `Uint8List` then you can do:

```dart
Uint8List.fromList(yourList);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually I want to read the file block by block as the file size may be too large to read at once. I use `openedRndAccssFile.read(blockSize)` to get the whole block into a list of type `List<Uint8>`. Then I call `readByte()` in the end to complete the final multibyte utf-8 character (if necessary), which means the list should be expandable and I need to figure out converting `int` output of `readByte()` to `Uint8`. Another option is to store everything as `int` but that would be an inefficient use of resources.

Comment: @Xfce4 I see, I added another option for that in the end of the answer. :)

Comment: Thank you. The last part would be helpful. Though, I would like to do all the operation on Uint8List or List<Uint8> from the beginning -if possible.